# Swift - Getting Error while using replacingOccurrence

Tags: swift

So I'm taking Udacity's Swift for Developers course. I attempted to look at the forums for this question but oddly, they were quiet. This is the programming prompt:

```
var forwardString = "stressed"
var backwardsString = forwardString.characters.reversed()
print(backwardsString)


var lottaLikes = "If likeyou wanna learn Swift likeyou should build lots of small apps cuz it's likea good way to practice."

var noLikes = lottaLikes.replacingOccurrences(of:"like", with:"")
print(noLikes)
```

For whatever reason, I keep getting this error message:

Be sure that you have replaced all occurences of the word "like" and removed any extra spaces.

What am I missing here? If you need clarification on this I would be happy to provide it.
Thank you

Comment: I think this "error message" isn't generated by Xcode, it maybe somewhere in context. Check the code again?

Comment: I put that code in a Playground and it works fine. If you wrap the `forwardString.characters.reversed()` with `String`, it'll look a little neater in in a Swift Playground, like so `String(forwardString.characters.reversed())`.

Comment: Same here. No issues in running above code in playground.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your code gets the job done, but only because your variable `lottaLikes` is written in a weird way. You usually would have two spaces surrounding the word "like" so just removing the word would leave 2 spaces in a row. I would suggest writing the following line:

```
var noLikes = lottaLikes.replacingOccurrences(of:"like ", with:"")
```

It may be that Udacity is not checking the actual output, but the code itself. If so, It may be looking for something like I wrote above.

If this still does not work, you may want to write another line like so:

```
var noExtraSpaces = noLikes.replacingOccurences(of: "  ", with: " ")
```